# Mosaic images in double precision pixel type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, mosaic

I am trying to mosaic the raster images, but those images are in the double-precision pixel type and their pixel depth is 64 bit.

How can I mosaic that raster image?

I am using ArcMap 10.2 version.
Actually, I need to mosaic the image with the 32-bit float but I have an image with pixel type double precision and I don't have knowledge about that type.

Comment: Well, first what have you tried and what is not working? "How do I do x" type questions, with little context, do not tend to not get much attention. Do you actually need a 64bit depth floating-point value? I cannot think of many applications that require that much decimal precision, it adds an increased effect of measurement error and has much larger storage requirements than 32bit. Please edit your comment to provide additional information.

Comment: Actually, I need to mosaic the image with the 32-bit float but I have an image with pixel type double precision and I don't have knowledge about that type. I am using ArcMap 10.2